# Why does passing console.log directly to promise's then not work?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've observed some strange behaviour when logging the output of promises

```
var promise = Promise.resolve('hello');

/* This prints 'hello' to console */
promise.then(function(val) { console.log(val); });

/* But this doesn't */
promise.then(console.log);
```

This is in chrome, not sure about other browsers.

Any ideas why this seemingly strange behaviour occurs?
Is this a bug in chrome, or intended behaviour?

Comment: Because functions in JavaScript aren't bound like they are in other languages, so `var x = console.log` and `console.log` are not bound to the same `this` object. Using `console.log.bind(console)` in place of `console.log` will make it work.

Comment: Additional information: The second `then` will work fine in Node.js, since they have explicitly bound the `console.log` to the `console`.